# Java library with different versions of Bouncy Castle

Tags: java, dependencies, bouncycastle

I'm creating a Java library that is dependent on [FIPS compliant Bouncy Castle](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bouncycastle/bc-fips) but I also want the same library to be compatible with the regular [Bouncy Castle](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on)

I know that I'll end up with two packages to be published to Maven, similar to how java-webauthn-server create their [minimal jar](https://github.com/Yubico/java-webauthn-server#additional-modules) that does not depend on Bouncy Castle.

So, my question is, what is the correct way to create a code that can instantiate one or the other version of the provider based on what the version of the library.

Here is my code that I use to instantiate a provider:

```
//import org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.BouncyCastleFipsProvider
import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider

...
//    Provider provider = new BouncyCastleFipsProvider()
    Provider provider = new BouncyCastleProvider()
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use reflection to instantiate the available provider:

```
Provider getProvider() throws ClassNotFoundException {
    try {
        return (Provider) Class.forName("org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.BouncyCastleFipsProvider").getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        // fallback
        return (Provider) Class.forName("org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider").getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();

    }
}
```

Comment: In fact, reflection is possibly the only sensible option ... given that the package names are different and the OP wants to avoid unconditional runtime dependencies on both library JARs.